# Symfony form contents change on Twig page

Tags: forms, twig, symfony-3.3, php-7.1

I have created an unsubscription page where users can go by clicking in email.

```
user/notification/5ad9a4b623f34/unsubscribe
```

I then load the user by the that specific user key and then show different contents based on if user had agreed to our T&C or not. i tried different ways but the form contents change on page refreshes (not always). For example I show a checkbox if user has not already agreed to our T&C. Sometimes it shows the checkbox and sometimes it doesn't for the same user on page refreshes.

Does anyone know of any such problem about Symfony forms displayed using Twig? I spent hours without getting any final ouput.

Thanks.

Comment: I have put the checkbox inside the if statement in the twig.

Comment: Maybe the query you are using to determine if the user accepted the T&C is returning different results. This can be because of wrong JOINS, etc. It can be the cache, try to clear the caches.

Comment: have tried to clear the browser cache as well as the symfony caches. There are no complex queries, I simply do it like this but sometimes the checkbox appear and sometimes not.  `{% if profile.acceptTermsAndConditions is not sameas(true) or profile.acceptTermsAndConditions is null %}`

Comment: Maybe it's because `acceptTermsAndConditions` sometimes returns false and sometimes it returns null? 
Or the sameas should be written like `same as` (with the space) [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/sameas.html)

Comment: yes did the same and it seems to be working now. is there any difference between `sameas` and `same as`?

Comment: Actually when I tried to resubmit the form after a few mins, it started giving the same problem again. its not the form token which had expired, it says that the value is not set.

Comment: Post `twig` template and why do you complicate your check that much? Just do `{% if profile.acceptTermsAndConditions is null or not profile.acceptTermsAndConditions %}`. Also you are not using a reverse proxy or anything right?